# Force Play Framework to listen on localhost only

Tags: playframework-2.0

How can you force the Play Framework listen on localhost only
i would like that the play will listen on the localhsot:9000 and not on 0.0.0.0:9000
so it won't be accessible to  external IP
i tried to use
http.address=127.0.0.1
on the application.conf , but it didn't seem to make any change.
using netstat i saw that play use 0.0.0.0:9000

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand your question. I think with http.address=127.0.0.1 and play "run 8080".. should attend on 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: @Gere, Thanks Gere , but how could i make it clearer. i don't want to expose my application to the external world. as you see i did use  http.address=127.0.0.1 on the application.conf. yet the process seems to bind to the 0.0.0.0 address which is open to connection to all IP. binding to 127.0.0.1 will accept connection only from the local host

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use "localhost" as the http.address target.

```
play start -Dhttp.address=localhost
```

For some reason, specifying 127.0.0.1 as `http.address` is causing it to bind to `0.0.0.0`, which seems like a bug to me. Using `localhost`, however, works.

Comment: Thanks mate , but it didn't help. i tried both play start -Dhttp.address=localhost and play start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 same results

Comment: That's disappointing. I'm using Play 2.0.4, and it seems to be working for me. You can try filing a bug on the Play Framework site.

Comment: i'm  using play 2.10.0. At least i'm on the right track and it is possible todo. so it must be something wrong on my environment. if no one else will suggest some other solution i will mark your answer as the accepted . thanks again

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, on Play 2.2. (Tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.)

Comment: This also works with `sbt` if you start it with `sbt -Dhttp.address=localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Sad hack around is simply to block off that port to the outside world. Below you're allowing local access, but banning everyone else. This will keep people from bypassing your proxy (i.e. getting around HTTPS if you terminate there).

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DROP
```

If you bork your `iptables` settings, just run the following to reset them. PS, don't screw with port 22 if your on a remote VM. ;)

```
iptables -F
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sbt -Dhttp.address=localhost
run
```