# Web app on VM server ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, linux, web-services, centos

Edit: I am making this question more generic

I am using Play! framework. I ran the dist command with no errors and unzip on a linux vm and I ran the ./appName file

```
$ ./appName
Play server process ID is xxxx
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://mydatabase:port/schema
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

The webpage myservername:9000/  shows `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.` 
I tried different ports, using the IP address of the server. Also the logs don't show any errors

Comment: Why not using port 80? Do you have another web server redirecting to your Play server?

Comment: @Kris No, and I tried different ports, same result

Comment: What does`netstat` show for port 9000?

Comment: Why are you starting your app as sudo?

Comment: @EJP netstat -nao | find 9000 give file not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a firewall. You can check by running `iptables --list` and changing the rules to allow access to your server

I noticed I had this line in iptables

```
reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a firewall or a network binding problem. The request is never making it to the play server. Can you test `curl -i http://localhost:9000/` from the server and see if you get a 200 response? Sometimes you might need to use `127.0.0.1` or the hostname itself. Then you'll know that the problem isn't the play server.

If that is the problem, see [ [Force Play Framework to listen on localhost only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370704/force-play-framework-to-listen-on-localhost-only) ] for the next step.

Comment: curl works how do I access the page from outside the server? I am familiar with Apache and tomcat

Comment: I tried ./appName -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dhttp.address=myvmip